# How to determine autocorrelation support for a chirp signal?

Tags: statistics, signal-processing, correlation

I have a chirp signal defined as following:
$$
x(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        e^{i\cdot\pi\cdot(B/pw)\cdot(t-pw/2)^2}, & \text{for } 0\leq n\leq \text{pw}\\
        0, & \text{else} 
        \end{array}\right\}
$$
where B, pw are constants. How can I calculate the support of the autocorrelaton of this signal?

thank you

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: from what I understood, the support of cross-correlation is 2*SP where SP is the support of the longer signal. so, I thought that when performing autocorrelation, the support will be just 2*SP where SP will be the support of the signal itself, but when I plotted it in matlab using xcorr, it was much bigger, and I wonder what have I misunderstood